# Flutter use NetworkImage as background

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

is there some way for using NetworkImage as background ?

I need create some box with network image and I need add some widgets over this image.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `decoration` attribute of `Container` to put the network image. You must also update the container size.

```
Container(
    decoration: 
         BoxDecoration(
             image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried only Image.network and its not working. But this working fine :) I found class Stack maybe it will be better.